# plane which passes through three points

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

[image]

I am confused as to how to answer this question because I don't understand how to incorporate the 12 into my answer. Any suggestions?

Comment: In three dimensions, there's a special trick. Call your three points $\tilde{x},\tilde{y}$ and $\tilde{z}$. Now choose one of the points to be the origin of the plane, say $\tilde{x}$. Now find the two displacement vectors relative to that point. Namely $\tilde{y}-\tilde{x}$ and $\tilde{z} - \tilde{x}$. Their cross-product is a normal vector to the plane. So compute $(\tilde{y}-\tilde{x}) \times (\tilde{z}-\tilde{x}),$ and then scale to get the first coordinate equal to $12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you find the normal vector, you can multiply it by a scalar such that the first entry in the normal vector times the scalar = 12. Then the vector will match. Multiplying the normal vector by a scalar doesn't change the fact that it is a normal vector to that plane.

For example, when I calculated the normal vector, I got $<-12,-6,3>$. To get this into the form they are looking for, I need to find x such that $-12 * x = 12$.

In this case, x is clearly -1, so we can then multiply the normal vector by -1.

This gets us $<12,6,-3>$ for an answer.

Comment: I got the equation for the plane : -12x-6y+3z-15=0

where do I go from here?

Comment: The normal vector is embedded into the plane equation: Your normal vector is <-12, -6, 3>.

Comment: AHHH! I did not account for the x value being -1! thank you! :)

Comment: I hope this helps your understanding.

Comment: I had been entering -6 and 3 instead of the 6 and -3 answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Draw a triangle with the three points at the vertices.  Now pick one point as a base for "tails" and find the vectors with heads at the other two points.  This gives two vectors. Knowing two vectors, how do you find a third perpendicular to both?  If you do this, you are ready to go.